# Reading From Files

Tags: c++, c++11

I was bit curious if I was going about this the wrong way. I am trying to read numbers from two different lists, sort the numbers, and then output ALL the numbers to a3rd file. I understand getline is probably not the best option but I still would like to use it.

list1 = 1,4, 5, 18

list2 = 2, 3, 15, 16

output = 1, 2, 3, 4,5, 7, 15,16 - what i should get

what i actually get - 1, 3, 5, 16

Here's a portion of the code

```
void sorted(std::ifstream &ifs, std::ifstream &ifs1, std::ofstream &ofs){
//while ((!ifs.eof()) & (!ifs1.eof())){

    //int number = 0;
    //int number1 = 0;
    std::string num1;
    std::string num2;
    //getline(ifs, num1);
    //getline(ifs1, num2);

    while(std::getline(ifs, num1) && std::getline(ifs1, num2)){
    int number = 0;
    int number1 = 0;
    std::stringstream ss1;
    std::stringstream ss2;
    ss1 << num1;
    ss2 << num2;
    ss1 >> number;
    ss2 >> number1;
        //while(ss1 >> number && ss2 >> number1)
        //{
            if (number < number1){
                ofs << number << std::endl;
                ss1 >> number;
                std::cout << "am i doing this right?";
            }
            else{
                ofs << number1 << std::endl;
                ss2 >> number1;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not simply store all numbers in e.g. a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which you then can [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), and output from the vector.

Comment: For the sake of the assignment, we weren't suppose to use a vector.

Answer (score 1):

`getline` is the best option, no doubt and it is always better than your commented line of code using `eof`. As Joachim mentioned in comment, you can first read the numbers from file to a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) container and call [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)  algorithm on top of vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are discarding one number in each pair each iteration because your `if (number < number1) ... else` block only ever writes one of the two numbers out.

Try...

```
        if (number < number1){
            ofs << number << std::endl;
            ofs << number1 << std::endl;
            ...
        }
        else{
            ofs << number1 << std::endl;
            ofs << number << std::endl;
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Oops, jumped the gun. I got 3 5 8 13 11 17, but i think i can figure it out from here. thanks. inputted 5 8 11 in 1 and then 3 13 17 in the 2nd